# Mysql query follow follower system

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following Tables

`followTable` with columns 
`userid` `followingid`

and

`userTable` with columns 
`userid` `username`

Now to find out who follows me assuming I'm user 1 
I run the query

```
SELECT userTable.username,  userTable.userid FROM userTable INNER JOIN followTable ON followTable.userid = userTable.userid   WHERE followTable.followingid = '1' order by followTable.datefollowed Desc
```

So I'm able to put this in and array an echo out in php

The result would be something like this

```
username     userid   

john           2

joe            5
```

Now I want to find out if I'm following the user by using the same query so that the output table would be something like this

```
username      userid     followinguser
john             2           0
joe              5           1
```

where 0 means I am not following the user and 1 means I am following the user.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to perform this query. I tried using a self join but to no avail.

Comment: what does followTable.followingid = '1' mean? Please post table's some data...

Comment: followTable.followingid = '1' mean pull out all results where the following id column in followTable = 1. In other words pull out all your followers.

Comment: I do not quiet follow @zerkms

Comment: @Kwaasi Djin: it means - what you need should be done with `LEFT JOIN`. Please bother of googling and reading of how to use it.

Comment: I'm aware of Left Joins but that doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT t1.userid,t1.username ,COALESCE(t2.followornot, 0) as followornot 
 from user t1 left join 
  (SELECT f.userid as fid,1 as followornot
  FROM follow f where f.followingid='youruseridhere' ) t2 on t1.userid=t2.fid
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d45002/21

Comment: @Kwaasi Djin: "duplicates" - that often means you've composed the join condition wrong

Comment: @KwaasiDjin Could you please kindly include some sample data for your two tables?

Comment: username userid followornot
john 00000000001 0
john 00000000001 0
james 00000000010 1
joe 00000000002 1
jon 00000000001 0
ann 00000000007 0
james 00000000002 0
helen 00000000003 0                                     helen 00000000003 0
helen 00000000003 1
John Steel 00000000005 0
Hanna Simonson 00000000006 0
ranya 00000000008 0
hrys 00000000009 0

Comment: @sel i'm sorry I do not know how to format table in stackoverflow comment

Comment: that is okay. but i meant the original data rows in table (usertable and follow table). the one you paste is the results after running the sql?

Comment: @sel the original follow table only has userid and following id with no duplicates. the table is about 100 rows deep so I wouldn't be able  to post it in a comment.

Comment: Not sure if i understand it correctly. Pls refer to the edited answer.